# Unable to find an inherited method for function ‘size’ for signature ‘"numeric"’

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(ggspatial)
library(ggmap)
library(basemaps)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

myMap <- get_map(location = myLocation, zoom = 4)
myMap <- get_map(
  location = myLocation, zoom = 4, source = "google",
  maptype = "satellite"
)
ggmap(myMap)
read.csv("TestData.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", col.names = TRUE)
View(TestData)
newsa <- TestData[, 2:4]
ggmap(myMap, extent = "device") +
  stat_density_2d(data = newsa, aes(
    x = DLongitude, y = DLatitude,
    fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..,
  )) +
  size(0.01, bins = 16, geom = "polygon") +
  scale_filled_gradient("red") +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)
```

The code works fine up to the second line [`aes()`] reproducing the map with contours.

From third line [`fill =` ] r says

> "Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill"

but the initial problem [in the question] still remains.

The data frame [newsa] looks like the following:

[image: A sample of my data frame]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bhxh.png)

Comment: Please edit your question such that your code becomes a  *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. Only include packages that you really need (never use `library(tidyverse)`). And include data (either generate it with code, or use data that ships with R). We do not have "TestData.csv" or "myLocation".

Comment: The arguments *size*, *bins* and *geom* belong (in)to `stat_density_2d` (*size* being a mapping argument (`aes(..., size = )`) instead of adding them as a plot component (`... + size(...) + ...`): https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html